# How do I remove spaces, brackets and everything in between using REGEX in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Cant seem to find the same question on here, so here goes,

my string that i want to edit is: `+44 (0)1234 123321` I want to remove:

1. All spaces
2. Both brackets
3. Anything inside the brackets

So it should output as `+441234123321`

How?

Ive already tried:

`const phoneRaw = phone.replace(/\([^\)\(]*\)/, "");`
`const phoneRaw = phone.replace(/[( )]/g);` <-- This gets rid of brackets and spaces

Comment: Why has this got negative rating for a simple question?

Comment: Because you're asking us to do your job. You should, at least, try it yourself, post your tries, and then let us help if you don't understand something

Comment: Do you not think I've already tried? Hence the reason I'm here in the first place, I dont understand REGEX in general if I'm honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let string = '+44 (0)1234 123321';
let regex = /\s+|\(.*?\)/g;
let result = string.replace(regex,'');
```

`\s+` matches any whitespace.
`\(.*\)` matches anything inside of parenthesis.

Comment: `\s*` also matches the emptiness between all characters. Is there any reason to prefer that over `\s+`?

Comment: Good catch, I'll fix that.

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate it

Comment: Needs a global flag (g), otherwise it will just replace the first space and nothing else.

Comment: Also, making it non-greedy would cover multiple sets of parenthesis `/\s+|\(.*?\)/g`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```js
let str = '+44 (0)1234 123321';
console.log(str.replace(/\(.*?\)|[^0-9+]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
phoneRaw = '+44 (0)1234 123321';

function clearPhoneNumber (phone) {
  return phoneRaw.replace(/(\(\d+\))|[^\d]/g, '');
}

clearPhoneNumber(phoneRaw);
```

It will replace anything in between `(...)` and anything that isn't a number.

If you want to keep the `+` sign, you can use this instead, inside that function:

`return phoneRaw.replace(/(\(\d+\))|[^\d|\+]/g, '');`